# ¿Como lanzo el interstitial sin cerrar el Maps?

Tags: android, admob

Tengo un pequeño problema, quiero poner un interstitial cuando la gente quiera mirar la direccion GPS en el Maps.

Pulsan, el intertitial sale pero al cerrarlo tambien cierra el maps, hay alguna manera de que el maps se lance al cerrar el interstitial o de que no se cierre solo? gracias por adelantado!!

```js
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cruzdelosreyes);
            ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fondocruzdelosreyes);
            
            Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.fondo2).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).centerCrop().into(imageView2);
            mapcruzdelosreyes = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mapcruzdelosreyes);
            mapcruzdelosreyes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               
               @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+27.726932+","+-18.025075+"&mode=d");
                    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                   
                   startActivity(mapIntent);
                    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-7914603828422129/7396169016");
                    AdRequest madRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                    interstitialAd.loadAd(madRequest);
                    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdLoaded() {
                            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                                interstitialAd.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El [anuncio interstitial](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial?hl=es) tiene un callback que es `onAdClosed()`, agregalo, aquí es donde detectarías se cerro el anuncio y realizarías el Intent para mostrar el mapa.

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
        }

        ...
        ...
        ...

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.

               Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+27.726932+","+-18.025075+"&mode=d");
               Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
               mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

               startActivity(mapIntent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: ahh genial!! muchas gracias!!!

Comment: lo acabo de añadir y funciona de lujo, un millón de gracias!